# Autofac instance scope resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a simple command architecture with your basic CommandBus, CommandHandlers, here is a simplified version of my command bus.

```
public class CommandBus : ICommandBus
    {        
        private readonly ICommandHandlerFactory _commandHandlerFactory;     

        public CommandBus(ICommandHandlerFactory commandHandlerFactory)
        {
            this._commandHandlerFactory = commandHandlerFactory;
        }

        public CommandSummary Send<T>(T command) where T : ICommand
        {

            try
            {
                var handler = _commandHandlerFactory.GetHandler<T>();
                handler.Handle(command);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return CommandSummary.Fail(e.Message, command);
            }
            return CommandSummary.Success(command, message: command.Message);
        }
    }
```

What I would like to add to this is the ability to execute commands in the background, or schedule a command for a later time. I am using the relatively new library [HangFire](http://hangfire.io/) (no SO tags for it yet), for the background job scheduling.

**The Issue**

I am registering a lot of my services using the InstancePerApiRequest scope, and when you run a job in the background, or at a later time, it is no longer part of that scope.

**Question**

Using Autofac, how does one register a service so that it can be resolved under multiple instance scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly detailed FAQ on working with per request scope and ways to handle "mixed" use cases like this on the Autofac doc site: http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html

Comment: Wow, I cant believe this didn't come up during my research! Thank you sir!